# Couchbase PagingAndSortingRepository .save() odd behaviour?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for looking at this question. I am using a Couchbase Server community-6.6.0 on Java Spring Boot (Java JDK version 1.8).

Problem Description: To interact with Couchbase I am using a PagingAndSortingRepository Repository. Each time I call .save() a new document representing a new instance of the Object I am using gets created in Couchbase. Also, when I retrieve an Object from Couchbase change the value of some field e.g., .setPassword() and then call .save() to make the change persistent then I get a new document (with a new Id) of that Object is created in Couchbase. It seems to me that many different revisions of that Object exist in the Database when I call .save(), I want to make sure that I am always working on the latest version of that instance of my Object/Entity.

I am really confused! What I am trying to do should be straightforward, every time I update a Java Entity I want the changes to be made persistent for that Document (with that Document id) in Couchbase. Perhaps I am missing something here. Please advice.

Partial view of the pom looks like:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Entities as follows:**

```
@Data
@Document
@CompositeQueryIndex(fields = {"id", "userName"})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @IdPrefix
    private String prefix;
    
    @Id @NotNull @GeneratedValue( delimiter = "::", strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;
    
    @Field
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=40)
    private String firstname;

    @Field
    @NotNull
    @QueryIndexed
    private String username;
    
    //Other attributes here ...
}


//ConfirmationToken Entity

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@CompositeQueryIndex(fields = {"id", "confirmationToken"})
public class ConfirmationToken {
    
    
    @IdPrefix
    private String prefix = "token";
    
    @Id @NotNull @GeneratedValue(delimiter = "::", strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;
    
    @Field
    @Reference
    private User user;
    
    @Field
    @QueryIndexed
    private String confirmationToken;
    
     //Other attributes here ...
    
}
```

UserRepository looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    
    @ScanConsistency(query = QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
    List<User> findByUsername(String username);

}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmationTokenServiceImpl implements ConfirmationTokenService {

    @Autowired
    private final ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;  
    
    @Override
    public void saveConfirmationToken(ConfirmationToken confirmToken) {
        confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmToken);
    }

    
}//end class
```

When I want to retrieve the User Object from Couchbase I do the following:

```
  //How do I ensure this Object is the latest version of that document?
  List<User> users = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

  //The following does not ensure that I get the latest version of that User document with that username
  User testUser = users.get(users.size()-1);
```

In some method I change field values of that Java Object i.e., User and then a new revision of that User Document gets created in the Database when I call .save(User Object). How do I update the fields of that User object and make that Document persistent in the Database without creating a new revision of that Document? Also, how do I ensure I always get and work on the latest version of *that* User Document?

```
public void someMethod(UserDTO regForm, final String contextPath) {
        
        User testUser = new User();
        
        testUser.setFirstname(regForm.getFname());
        testUser.setLastname(regForm.getSname());

        //Make User persistent
        userRepository.save(testUser);
        
        //Create the confirmation token for that User instance
        final ConfirmationToken confirmToken = new ConfirmationToken(testUser);

        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmToken);
}
```

In this Method I have another Class called ConfirmationToken that has a reference to a User Object. This is to associate each ConfirmationToken instance with a specific User Instance. When I call the following method to change the User password a new document with a new id is created for the User in the Database. I cannot understand how to update the current instance. Please help.

```
    public void changeUserPassword(ConfirmationToken confirmToken, ResetPassDTO resetPassForm) {
        
        //Retrieve the User instance that is associated with that Token 
        final User testUser = confirmToken.getUser();
        
        if (testUser.getEmail().equals(resetPassForm.getEmail())) {
        
            //Get the Hash of the User's password
            final String encryptedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(resetPassForm.getNewPassword());
            testUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
        
            //Enable the user account - since email ownership is also verified
            testUser.setIsEnabled(true);

            userRepository.save(testUser);
            
        }
        
        //Delete the Confirmation Token entity      
        confirmationTokenService.deleteConfirmationToken(confirmToken); 
        
    }
```

**Update:**

It seems that I had to go back and work on my domain modelling for the Entities. More specifically to think of how couchbase is doing docs embedding and when to do referencing. In my example, the ConfirmationToken instance holds a reference to a User instance. In reality the ConfirmationToken embeds the User instance in the same JSON doc. I cannot access the **actual** User object I want though. In other words, it seems that I cannot dereference and get the User instance by following the id of User object from the ConfirmationToken instance. **My solution:** I introduced a `uuid` field in the User object, I then get the reference for a User instance from ConfirmationToken, then I call `userRepository.findByUuid(userFromToken.getUuid());` only then I was able to get the actual User object that I wanted. My question is why Couchbase spring SDK cannot do this dereferencing automatically? Also, it seems that when I change the value of some attribute the change does not happen on the actual object but on the embedding, so every time I need to do this dereferencing to get to the real object manually. This is similar to MongoDB @DBRefs?? Not sure how if there is a solution with N1QL though and NEST queries? Can I achieve this with N1QL?

Comment: Hi there, can you post your entity mapping? It looks like there is something wrong there. If the document already exists, it should be updated instead of creating a new one, my guess is that the id is not being loaded somehow and then the sdk thinks that it is a new document. the behaviour you want is exactly how the SDK is supposed to work.

Comment: Hello @deniswsrosa and thank you for your reply.  As you mentioned "my guess is that the id is not being loaded somehow and then the sdk thinks that it is a new document." does this relates to the design decision of Couchbase not do introduce the doc-id as the id of the instance? How I can do dereferencing on the actual object? Please see my comment from above under "Update"

Comment: Can you add your code in a git repo? I'm pretty sure it is just a misconfiguration on your entity or some strange dependency.